# What does 'TypeError: connect() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 3 were given' with python-oracledb 1.0 mean?

Tags: python, oracle, python-oracledb

The [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) 1.0 code:

```
import oracledb
import os

un = os.environ.get("PYTHON_USERNAME")
pw = os.environ.get("PYTHON_PASSWORD")
cs = "localhost/orclpdb1"

c = oracledb.connect(un, pw, cs)
```

gives the error:

```
TypeError: connect() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The same error occurs when creating a connection pool:

```
pool = oracledb.create_pool(un, pw, cs, min=4, max=4)
```

or

```
pool = oracledb.SessionPool(un, pw, cs, min=4, max=4)
```

How do I fix this?

[Update: in python-oracledb 1.0.0 the message started with 'TypeError: wrapped() takes ...'.  In version 1.0.1 the 'wrapped' was changed to the name of the python-oracledb API that had the error.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error will come with a line number that points you at the connection or pool creation call. The solution is to use keyword parameters like:

```
c = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs)
```

or

```
pool = oracledb.create_pool(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs, min=4, max=4)
```

The `oracledb.connect()` and `oracledb.create_pool()` (and deprecated
`oracledb.SessionPool()`) parameters are keyword, not positional. This complies
with the Python Database API spec [PEP 249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/).

Although the solution is to use keyword parameters, the message mentions positional parameters which seems contradictory.  This is because PEP 249 allows one positional parameter like `c = oracledb.connect("un/pw@cs")`.  Your original call used positional parameters so the driver assumed that's the argument style you were trying to use - but only one positional argument is allowed so you got an error. I don't recommend using `"un/pw@cs"` because there can be parsing problems if your passwords contains "/" or "@".